# Eclipse + JBossAS Tools doesn't show JBoss Community server Adapters

Tags: eclipse, jboss

After accidentally losing the only Eclipse installation where I managed to install the JBoss Community server adapters successfuly (it required a very specific version of JBoss Tools), I'm trying to rebuild an Eclipse installation that shows the pesky Eclipse JBoss Community Server adapters.

I tried Eclipse Indigo + JBoss Tools 3.3 and Eclipse Juno + JBoss Tools 3.3. I install the Java EE version, go to "Download additional server adapters", install the JBossAS Tools, but the adapters still don't show up in the  "New Server" list. I'm about to give up and buy myself an IntelliJ IDEA license, but I thought it wouldn't hurt to ask if anyone around here knows a proper installation path that makes the JBoss Community adapters "magically" apear...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. In case anyone is wondering why adapters disappeared after some upgrade, JBoss Tools doesn't work well with Java 5. Use Java 6 and the problem is gone.

Answer (score 1):

You have to install eclipse plugin "JST Server Adapter" before installing "JBossAS Tools"

cf. bug : https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBIDE-10469